# I upgraded Xuntubu 12.10 to 14.10 Utopic Daily build BY Mistake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, xubuntu

I accidentally added a line of source for Utopic to sources.list. And later my system can't get into GUI. While trying to fix the problem I accidentally typed in command sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. So tragedy happened: my system was upgraded to 14.10 utopic daily built! which I don't want! what's worse, becuase it was upgrading from 12.10 to 14.10, a lot of dependency can't resolve, and many services stopped working. The worst thing is, I still can't get into GUI. What should I do for this circurmstance? I'm a newbie in Linux/Unix. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to re-install Xubuntu with a disk.

If you don't have a backup, click `Try Xubuntu` when the message pops up and copy the files from your hard drive to a thumb drive.

Then run the install and either erase the disk, or if you dual boot, select `Replace Xubuntu`.

I would recommend installing the newest [14.04](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) if you are already re-installing.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am about to do as you mentioned. However I'd like to know how does an upgrade from 12.10 to 14.10 destroy the system? just curious.